# How to get the total quantity of items ordered via Admin Panel

Tags: magento-1.7, sales-order, admin-panel, quantity, totals

I'm using Magento 1.7. In creating new order via admin panel, how do you get the total quantity of items ordered?

Comment: what you mean by `total quantity of items ordered` ? Means no of items which is ordered in a order?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Because I want to add some fee based on the quantity of the items ordered in the order, prior to submission of the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Order object then using `getTotalItemCount(`) ,you can get  no of items ordered in an order.

```
<?php $_order = $this->getOrder() ?>
<?php echo $_order->getTotalItemCount();?>
```